# Alternating Row Colour with Conditional Formatting in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2011

Does anyone know how to create a formula that causes the row colour to alternate when using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Format -> Conditional Formatting`  with two conditions with these formulas:

1. `=MOD(ROW(),2)=0`
2. `=MOD(ROW(),2)=1`

then apply your custom format.

Comment: Format -> Conditional formating brings up a box.  Clicking + to add a rule gives me a choice of 2 color scale, 3 color scale, Data bar, icon sets, classic. Checking each of these in turn shows no place I can enter a formula.  Mac Excel 2011

Comment: Choose Classic.  The dialog changes, 'Format only cells that contain' should appear - change thst selection to 'Use a formula to determine which ceels to format'